# Creating a comman named class dependency in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I am creating a fastapi server where a APIRouter hast lots of endpoint and all of them are accepting same request body. Is there any way I can omit that from all function in that routers and specify at single place

Consider an example where I am building simple calculator server which accepts two number num1 and num2 with a requests body which is json has bunch of information like version of request, sender of request etc. and I want num1 and num2 in same variable but json body in `requests_info` field.

Here is my
`main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from calculator import calculate

# FastAPI app object
fastapi = FastAPI()

# User fulfillment routes
fastapi.include_router(calculate.router, prefix="/calculator", tags=['calculator'])
```

My `calculator.py` looks like

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/add")
async def add(num1: int, num2: int, request: Request) -> int:
    req_info = await request.json() # here I don't want to put request: Request every time but want to specify in dependency and want to access with name request 
    return num1 + num2

@router.post("/multiply")
async def mul(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
    req_info = await request.json()
    return num1 * num2


@router.post("/subtract")
def sub(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
    return num1 - num2
```

In this example I have specified `request: Request` in `add` and not in other methods. But I want to access `requests` without specifying there. Is there any way I can do it using dependency.

I know we can use https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/  but how to created a named dependency here.

Comment: This would generally depend on _why_ you're manually decoding the `request` object. Instead, each function should just get the values they need, and if they need resolving through `request` for some reason, you'd move that out to a common dependency that does it for you. One of the goals of the dependency resolution in FastAPI is that anything that the controller depends on _is passed as an argument to the function_, so its very clear where anything originates from; if a function doesn't need the dependency, it doesn't need to be resolved.

Comment: I am writing a wrapper where I want user to use `request` json along with url param. It depends on user if they want it or not. I am generating all the include_router dependency and want it to be easier for user to implement this.

Comment: You might want to use something like fastapi-utils' class-based views in that case: https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/ - another option is to create your own custom router and implement something similar yourself: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router